# AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with User.password_hash has an attribute 'count'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have created a User table in models.py file that contains

**models.py**

```
class User(Base):

    __tablename__ = "users"
    userid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(15), unique=True)
    usertype = Column(Boolean)
    gender = Column(String(1))
    age = Column(Integer)
    phone = Column(VARCHAR(15))
    password_hash = Column(VARCHAR(128))

    @classmethod
    def create_password(cls, password):
        cls.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
        return cls.password_hash

    @classmethod
    def check_password(cls, password):
        return check_password_hash(cls.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.userid) + ":" + self.username
```

I then use the check_password functions that I have written in functions.py file:

**functions.py**

```
def search_user(username):
    return session.query(models.User).filter_by(username=username).all()

def password_checking(password, username):
    usr = search_user(username)[0]
    while True:
        if usr.check_password(password) == False:
            print("Passwords do not match.")
        else:
            break
```

Also I have added some of the users inside the database:

*db*

```
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+------+-----------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| userid | username    | usertype | gender | age  | phone     | ticket_price | password_hash                                                                                  |
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+------+-----------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | ashishadmin |        1 | M      |   24 | 750792699 |         NULL | pbkdf2:sha256:150000$scvDUqJm$8dd6cf55b182391e2558134383d6e91befec40a9e4176a860f3e2158ebaae161 |
|      2 | ashish01    |        0 | M      |   24 | 123456789 |         NULL | pbkdf2:sha256:150000$ZTSGjGMh$21bb1cab7ea515865645031c993bce532d787f9b2c402246d0387f921ccf0ba8 |
|      3 | ashish02    |        0 | M      |   24 | 963852741 |         NULL | pbkdf2:sha256:150000$ZDajskIw$f27e76c5d1bcfb2019ffe01d74ddf2381fa61df72cdf830ca689a2aa057ff60c |
+--------+-------------+----------+--------+------+-----------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now when I try to test the check password function using:

```
print(password_checking("testing123", "ashish01"))
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\myenv\ticket_booking\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 747, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.comparator, key)
AttributeError: 'Comparator' object has no attribute 'count'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\myenv\ticket_booking\functions.py", line 95, in <module>
    print(password_checking("testing123", "ashish01"))
  File "c:\myenv\ticket_booking\functions.py", line 83, in password_checking
    if usr.check_password(password) == False:
  File "c:\myenv\ticket_booking\models.py", line 47, in check_password
    return check_password_hash(cls.password_hash, password)
  File "c:\myenv\ticket_booking\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\security.py", line 218, in check_password_hash
    if pwhash.count("$") < 2:
  File "c:\myenv\ticket_booking\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 238, in __getattr__
    util.raise_(
  File "c:\myenv\ticket_booking\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with User.password_hash has an attribute 'count'
```

I have also tried using the function before in the add_user function defined inside function.py file in order to check the re entered password which runs fine, but I can't understand why this way doesn't work and gives me an error.

**functions.py**

```
password = getpass("Enter password: ")
    pass_len = len(password)
    while pass_len < 8:
        print("Password length should be greater or equal to 8, please enter again.")
        password = getpass("Enter password: ")
        pass_len = len(password)
    password_hash = models.User.create_password(password)

    while True:
        re_password = getpass("Re-enter password: ")
        if models.User.check_password(re_password) == False:
            print("Passwords do not match.")
        else:
            break
```

**Note**: I am using werkzeug.security in order to create the password hash.

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/4200) is the best match I'm getting by looking it up online. I can't easily test it myself, but it seems it's possible your `password_hash` isn't actually a `Column` object, somehow. Your code seems fine to me, however, apart from the weird redefinition of `password_hash` in the `User` model (where it's first set to `None` for no reason)

Comment: Why is `check_password` a classmethod?  You want it to be an instance method, so it checks the value of the user's `password` attribute, not that of the class, which is a column.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I was doing that way initially, but that would give a TypeError.

Comment: @OctaveL I tried using `session.execute(select([models.User.password_hash]))` just to check if password_hash is a column object, and it ran fine. Running a loop on the object gave me all the hash key rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by querying a list of usernames with their stored hash key. Then I compared the entered username to the username displayed in the list and extracted the relative hash key which I next used in the password_checking function.

*models.py**

```
    @classmethod
    def check_password_after_signup(cls, password, password_hash):
        return check_password_hash(password_hash, password)

    @classmethod
    def check_password_before_signup(cls, password):
        return check_password_hash(cls.password_hash, password)
```

*functions.py*

```
def password_checking(username, password):
    while True:
        usr = search_user(username)[0]
        status = session.execute(
            select([models.User.username, models.User.password_hash])
        )
        for row in status:
            if row[0] == username:
                result = models.User.check_password_after_signup(password, row[1])
        if result == False:
            print("Passwords do not match.")
            password = getpass("Re-enter password: ")
        else:
            break
```